# How to generate a binary file? C#

Tags: c#, binaryfiles, binarywriter

I need to make a method that generates a binary (4 bytes long), receives List of integers and writes this List one by one in the file. So, I have this:

```
public void FrameCodesBinaryWriter(List<int> frameCodes)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(binaryFilePath,  FileMode.Create)) // destiny file directory.
    {
        using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < frameCodes.Count; i++)
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(frameCodes[i]);
            }
            binaryWriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

is this correct? or some other solution please

Comment: Are you testing us?  You can know if it is correct -- what happened when you tested it?

Comment: the file is generated, but I only want to make sure that is correct

Comment: Tip: you don't need to explicitly call Close() on `binaryWriter`. The `using` statement takes care of doing that correctly.

Comment: If you want to make sure it is correct, why not use a `BinaryReader` to read back the values and check if the numbers are equivalent? This is *very simple debugging*.

Comment: Candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to close `binaryWriter` because you have a `using` clause anyway. `binaryFilePath` needs to be a field of the class, apart from that it looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

As it is it should work fine. Here is a refactored version, you can pick and choose which bits of the refactoring you like.

```
public void WriteFrameCodesAsBinary(IEnumerable<int> frameCodes)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(binaryFilePath,  FileMode.Create))
    using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        foreach (int frameCode in frameCodes) {
            binaryWriter.Write(frameCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I would rename the function to describe the action it will do. `FrameCodesBinaryWriter` sounds more like a class name to me.

If you don't need the ordering of the `List<T>`, it might be an idea to accept an `IEnumerable<T>` instead. That way you can be more flexible about what you pass in.

Some people like to stack their using statements to remove a layer of nesting (code indentation). Personally I'm not a massive fan of this, but it's a matter of personal taste and style.

Using an `IEnumerable<T>` forces us to use `foreach`, but even with `List<T>` it can look cleaner/make it more obvious you are iterating through the list.

As previously mentioned, if you are using `using` you don't need to explicitly close the binary writer - that will be done automatically when the `using` block is exited.